# Event registration on loco.ubuntu.com

Tags: locoteams

On Planet Ubuntu there was a post asking RSVP to an Ubuntu Jam organized by the Californian LoCo. The event linked to [loco.ubuntu.com event entry](http://loco.ubuntu.com/events/ubuntu-california/1198/detail/), where we could enter our RSVP status. Is it possible to implement a similar system for our LoCo page on Ubuntu Wiki?

**EDIT**

As @JorgeCastro pointed out in the comments, LoCos can register events at [loco.ubuntu.com](http://loco.ubuntu.com/). But what is the procedure to register an event there?

Comment: I don't get this question, why not just add your own entry in the loco directory? that's what it's there for!

Comment: @JorgeCastro I can do that? And it's for everything including regular local events like monthly meetup.

Comment: Yep, it's for all events for everybody, jet a mail to ubuntu-lococontacts if you have any questions.

Comment: Yeah the problem is I don't know the details of how to set that up, I just know it's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters you cannot add an event for a team unless you are a member of that team.

The procedure for registering an event is as follows:

1. Go to http://loco.ubuntu.com/events/
2. Click on Add Team Event - Login through the LP SSO if you are not already logged in
3. Submit the details for the new event

You will then have a publishable link to the event detail. You will also find a direct link to the RSVP page in the detail page of the event.

Comment: Any member of the team can post events, regardless of their position in the LoCo?

Comment: yes , and just Select a Team to add (Events or Meetings)